# How do you add a new directory in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am currently taking a Computing GCSE, and I have got a Linux Controlled Assessment, and this is one of the tasks:

> Create a directory within your home directory. Name it A452. Navigate to your new A452 directory. Type `touch mynametextfile`, where `myname` is your
>   first name.

I tried adding a new folder called A452, and then opening the terminal and typing `touch matthewtextfile`, but that didn't work. I am very new to Linux, and I tried Wikipedia, so what should I do?

Edit: It turns out that it was in my Home folder, not my newly created one!

Comment: Try `ls` to show the contents of the current directory , `pwd` to show the current directory and `cd` to change it.

Comment: check if you are typing touch cmd inside your newely created folder.

Comment: Use `mkdir` to create a directory, `cd` to change the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your terminal:

```
$ cd ~               # move to your home directory
$ mkdir A452         # create directory named A452
$ cd A452            # mv to that directory
$ touch mynametextfile  # create file "mynametextfile"
```

Comment: I can't because it's marked as an accepted answer